# How to stop consuming messages in a camel route when destination unavailable

Tags: apache-camel

I'm bridging IBM and ActiveMQ queues with Camel.

Everything works ok, but when destination becomes unvailable because of network problem all the processed messages get lost.

Camel should stop consuming from origin if destination is unavailable and start again when it becomes available, but I don't find correct pattern/configuration to do that.

I'm configuring routes like following one from IBM MQ to IBM MQ, but I'm looking for a way to solve any combination of IBM and ActiveMQ.

```
<bean id="lsywmq" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <bean class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
            <property name="transportType" value="1" />
            <property name="hostName" value="${mq_lsy_hostname}" />
            <property name="port" value="${mq_lsy_port}" />
            <property name="queueManager" value="${mq_lsy_queuemanager}" />
            <property name="channel" value="${mq_lsy_channel}" />
            <property name="useConnectionPooling" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="wmq" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <bean class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
            <property name="transportType" value="1" />
            <property name="hostName" value="${mq_hostname}" />
            <property name="port" value="${mq_port}" />
            <property name="queueManager" value="${mq_queuemanager}" />
            <property name="channel" value="${mq_channel}" />
            <property name="useConnectionPooling" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
    allowUseOriginalMessage="false" >
    <route id="EFF2AVIO">
        <from uri="lsywmq:queue:{{mq_lsy_queue}}"/>
        <to uri="wmq:queue:{{mq_queue}}"/>
            </route>
</camelContext>
```

I would like to get it working as a pipeline, if it get stuck at destination, all the pipe remains stucked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `transacted` property of the JMS connectionFactory to `true`.
This won't actually stop your consumer, but you'll get the Guaranteed Delivery EIP pattern implemented, so your messages wont't be lost any more.
From now on you could also provide [redelivery policy](https://activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy) for the ActiveMQ connectionFactory, something that will be relevant for you, e.g. a long `redeliveryDelay`

You may use `JMSConfiguration` object to configure JMS [options](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jms-component.html#_options) like this

```
<bean id="wmq" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="transacted" value="true"/>
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="myConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
    <property name="transportType" value="1" />
    <property name="hostName" value="${mq_lsy_hostname}" />
    <property name="port" value="${mq_lsy_port}" />
    <property name="queueManager" value="${mq_lsy_queuemanager}" />
    <property name="channel" value="${mq_lsy_channel}" />
    <property name="useConnectionPooling" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I don't find any way to insert transacted property on any other place that adding <transacted/> tag in the route between <from/> and <to/>, but doing this way there is no rollback, when destination is available again no failed delivery message arrives

Comment: I've set transacted with: `code`<from uri="lsywmq:queue:{{mq_lsy_queue}}?transacted=true"/>`code`